# Updating a column in MySQL using its previous value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table in mysql 'url_map' with 2 columns: id, url with some values populated in it. Something like this:

`+----+-----------------------------------------+                                                                                 | id | url                                     |                                                                                 +----+-----------------------------------------+                                                                                 |  1 | http://myserver.mywebsite.com/file1.txt |                                                                                 |  2 | http://myserver.mywebsite.com/file2.txt |                                                                                 +----+-----------------------------------------+`

My requirement is to update the 'url' of every row in the table to a new value using it's previous value.

`+----+---------------------------------------------+                                                                                 | id | url                                         |                                                                                 +----+---------------------------------------------+                                                                                 |  1 | https://mynewserver.mywebsite.com/file1.txt |                                                                                 |  2 | https://mynewserver.mywebsite.com/file2.txt |                                                                                 +----+---------------------------------------------+`

If you see the changes, in every row, the value of 'url' has been changed from

- http:// to https://
- myserver to mynewserver

rest other things in the url are kept as they were previously.

Can anyone please help me out in writing the query for this ?

Comment: Replace function can be a start point

Answer (score 1):

You can use previous value directly in the update statement

```
UPDATE your_table t SET t.url = REPLACE(REPLACE(t.url, 'http://', 'https://'), 'myserver', 'mynewserver')
```

Answer (score 0):

i would simply do an `UPDATE` statement like:

```
UPDATE url_map
   SET url = REPLACE(REPLACE(url, 'http', 'https'),'myserver ','mynewserver')
```

or if you want to do it in one `REPLACE` (as http and myserver is basically one string)

```
UPDATE url_map
   SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http://myserver', 'https://mynewserver')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your example said, you can use **replace method**.

```
Update url_map
Set    url = replace(url, 'http://myserver', 'https://mynewserver');
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test this yet, but in theory this should work:

```
UPDATE `url_map` SET url = REPLACE(url, "http://myserver", "https://mynewserver")
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: My bad, for whatever reason I had the "SELECT" syntax still in mind. Updated it.

Answer (score -2):

You have to create a procedure. In the procedure loop through the rows and do the change. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html for a detailed description.

Comment: You dont need a procedure in this case, is much easier do a simple update. In other case, the procedure could be a good solution :)